# Install pandas for python 3

Tags: 16.04, python

I have both Python 2.7.12 and 3.5 installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 system. I installed pandas using `pip install pandas`. When I `import pandas` in python 2 it works fine. But when I `import pandas` in python3 it throws an error saying:

```
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
```

How do I install pandas for python3?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[pandas install documents](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html):

Python2 and Python3 uses different version of pandas.

For Python3 you can install it using `apt install`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

In order to install it using `pip`, you should use `pip3` for `Python3`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo -H pip3 install pandas
```

Comment: I suggest to use python3-pandas using sudo apt-get otherwise there is chance that you might get this error.  "numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  return f(*args, **kwds)"